# Accuracy of Chrome developer tools waterfall diagram

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to increase JavaScript performance for loading some data through an Ajax call. To test performance of my changes I'm using both

- JS timestamps (`console.time('someFunction');` and `performance.now()`)
- and using Waterfall diagram in Chrome dev tools

I see discrepancies.
For timestamps Starting time is inside `<head>` in first line of JavaScript on the page. Then Endpoint is just before Ajax call is requested.
Before code changes:

- Timestamps difference average is **38ms**
- Waterfall Ajax call starts in average at **227ms**

After changes to code (code responsible for these Ajax call moved to the top of JS and moved outside the document ready event (jQuery)

- Timestamps average: **68ms** (very strange)
- Waterfall average: **197ms**

How should I interpret these changes?

Comment: Your measuring different things, the chrome tools will measure the HTTP round trips, the Js will measure when you code actually runs. Which one to use depends on which of these your trying to optimise. If your saying these are wrong then you need to show us some code, my guess is your not awaiting async requests

Comment: If you want to rule out Chrome then you can use a transport layer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or for even more detail [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: @Liam I have parts of the content loading from API based on site settings (geolocation..) user location and user search behavior (location and keywords). This has been designed a few years ago and updated through years. This code is wrapped inside document ready (jQuery). I'm trying to optimize this code to load that API content faster (make these call quicker). First step was to rearange some code (move this part to the top or bundle - just after jQuery) and remove document ready  wrap. This makes HTTP round a little faster, but my JS test slower.

Comment: can this mean that the initial timestamp (console.time('function') is being fired later (page loading time) after my changes, but overall these API calls are executed faster?